# How do I make a raspberry pi a node in the testnet blockchain ? Is it possible?

Tags: blockchain, raspberry-pi

Me and my friends have decided to do a small project using 3-4 RPIs and making transactions between them using smart contracts.

The smart contracts will *trigger events* based on weather or any real time data, and will make a transaction to the other RPI's in this small blockchain, which will then trigger a function that will turn on a LED or display something.

First of all, **is it feasible** ?

Then , would i need to download the whole testnet blockchain on the RPI's or there exists **another solution that will need less time or space** ?

Finally, what **frameworks or packages would i need to do it** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code will need access to the Blockchain via an Ethereum node (geth or parity for instance).  Running those on a Raspberry Pi using testnet might work, but a more attractive solution might be to use a cloud provider for access to the Ethereum block chain.  Check out Infura (https://infura.io/).  As far as frameworks go, if node.js works, checkout [truffle](http://truffleframework.com/) and [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) or [ethjs](https://github.com/ethjs/ethjs).  If you opt for truffle + infura, here's an additional helpful [read](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider).